# Latex gives error if I put an equation in the title of a section

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, equations

I've a bit of a weird question. I would like to put an equation in the section title (I'm using `book`) but LaTex spits out the following error:

```
    [31] [32]Making bbold25.tfm from C:\Users\unknown\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\source\jknappen\sauter\bbold25.mf...
Running miktex-mf.exe...
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (MiKTeX 2.9)

(C:\Users\unknown\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\source\jknappen\sauter\bbold25.

mf

! I can't find file `b-bbold'.

l.2 input b-bbold

                 ;

Please type another input file name

! Emergency stop.

l.2 input b-bbold

                 ;

Transcript written on bbold25.log.

miktex-maketfm.exe: Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

miktex-maketfm.exe: Data: bbold25.tfm

 5.
! Font U/bbold/m/n/24.88=bbold25 at 24.88pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.2280 \chapter{The $beta$}

?
```

I've tried to debug and found that there is no problem with my setup (packages, etc.) because I can use equation in titles when I've deleted all my previous chapters. Subsequently, I tried deleting each chapter one at the time to determine what chapter causes the problem and, weirdly, it turns out that all the chapters are not compatible with my section. So in other words, I can put equations in titles if I start a new document, but for some reason it doesn't work with my existing dissertation.

I would also like to mention that the error printed above is mentioning `MiKTex`, which I have installed on my computer, but I'm using TeXworks because I like it more. This may have something to do with the problem? If anybody could help me with this problem then that would be great.

Best regards,

Edit to show the code that is not working:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Blabla}

\begin{equation}
e^{i 2 \pi \mathcal{N}}=\mathbb{1} \Rightarrow \mathcal{N}=n' \;,\; n' \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}

\section{The $\beta$}


\end{document}
```

At the moment that I would delete the equation above, then it does work.

Also, this code does work:

```
\begin{document}

\chapter{Blabla}

\begin{equation}
e^{i 2 \pi \mathcal{N}}= \Rightarrow \mathcal{N}=n' \;,\; n' \in 
\end{equation}

\section{The $\beta$}

\end{document}
```

So it seems to be related to the `\mathbb` syntex.

Comment: The *first* error is the relevant one here, and this is `! I can't find file b-bbold'.` Is seems that you are `\input`ing a file not installed in your system.

Comment: Please reduce your document to a small, yet *complete* document allowing us to reproduce the problem and add it to your question.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, thank you for replying. I have two questions though: i) how come it does work when it is the only chapter and ii) how do I install `input` ing file on my computer?

Comment: what I meant is that (apparently) your code is trying to load a package that doesn't exist. The best course of action now is to produce the short, *complete* document allowing us to reproduce the problem (as I mentioned in my previous comment), and add it to your question.

Comment: You have installed the MiKTeX packages `bbold` and `bbold-type1`? Your MiKTeX is uptodate?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've edited my original post with a code that does not work. Of course, in addition to that I'm using many packages but I didn't want to post them all to make sure that it doesn't get too long.

Comment: Your code is missing the `amssymb` package (for `\mathbb`). Load it: `\usepackage{amssymb}`. Does the error persist?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I've recently (within the last month) installed MiKTeX to try it out, so I think it would be up to date. I didn't install the packages you are referring to deliberately, but maybe they came with the installation process?

Comment: Yeah, I still get the same error. Also, \mathbb was working fine until now. Do you think it would help if post all the packages that I'm using?

Comment: @Hunter: Run the package manager to see, whether the packages `bbold` and `bbold-type1` are installed. And yes, make a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). But do not forget the word "minimal".

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I've added a working code, which implies that the problem is due to the `\mathbb` command. At this point I'm really confused. I will try to figure out if I have `bbold` and `bbold-type1` package installed.

Comment: @Hunter: You have forgotten to load package `bbold`: `\usepackage{bbold}`. And MiKTeX package `bbold-type1` should be installed to avoid bitmap fonts.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I've finally managed to install bbold-type1 package, but unfortunatly it my code is still not working. It is so weird and I'm getting quite desperate, should I give up?

Comment: Ok, I've change from every `mathbb` syntax to `mathbbm` and now it's working. I do think it is very strange that it isn't working with `mathbb`, but so be it. Thanks a lot for the help @HeikoOberdiek and @GonzaloMedina

Comment: @Hunter: That's a different package, `\mathbbm` is provided by package `bbm`. And in TeX Live I get a bitmap font (`bbm10.600pk`). Vector fonts (Type 1, ...) are preferred for PDF.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it is not the ideal solution, but I don't know what else to do? I find Latex really confusing, I still haven't managed to bbold-type1 because it gives errors.  I can't really get around using math in the title. And another thing I noticed last night is that the getting rid rid of all the `mathbb` allowed me change fontsize, whereas before Latex only allowed me to use 10pt, now I can use any size I want to.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the examples shown don't possibly match the error message.